Query cache management in database servers
I remember a bug in which I issued the same database query over and over in a loop. It made me wonder if the server caches the datasets returned by the queries, and  how it decides what queries to save.

The most recent ones?

The textually-longest SQL?

The ones that returned the longest recordsets?

The ones that involve the most relational links?

The ones that took longest to compute?

Ones that tied up the most server volumes?

Ones directed at servers that are very busy?

Queries from management dashboards?

Queries from distant lands?

Ones issued by interactive terminals, as opposed to overnight batch runs?


Other people's jobs seem easy until you think about what they have to do.

Database engines have grown to be complex. They may introduce indexes "on their own". Some even save/cache how to answer a query (execution plan) rather than what, at one particular moment in time, its result was - think about intervening CRUD.
